# Why is the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\tan^{-1}(x)$?

Tags: calculus

My textbook says the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ is $\tan^{-1}(x)$.

To confirm this to myself I took the derivative of $\tan^{-1}(x)$ expecting to get $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ , but instead I ended up with $-\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}$. So why is $\tan^{-1}(x)$ the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ if the  derivative of $\tan^{-1}(x)$ is not $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$? Shouldn't the derivative of the antiderivative of a function give you the original function?

Comment: The $\tan^{-1}x$ here means $\arctan x$, not $1/\tan x$.

Comment: Oh, that would explain it then- Thanks

Comment: Another example of why  $\tan^{-1}$ is terrible notation.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Good thing that we have $\operatorname{atan}(x)$ (rare) and $\arctan(x)$ to fall back on.

Answer (score 8):

$$
\begin{align}
\arctan(x) &= y\\
x &= \tan(y)\\
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} x &= \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} \tan(y)\\
1 &= y' \sec^2(y)\\
y'&=\dfrac{1}{\sec^2(y)}\\
y'&=\dfrac{1}{\tan^2(y)+1}\\
y'&=\dfrac{1}{x^2 + 1}
\end{align}
$$

Because $x = \tan(y)$

Answer (score 2):

$$x=\arctan y$$
$$y=\tan x$$
$$\frac {dy}{dx}=\sec^2x=1+\tan^2 x=1+y^2$$

$$\frac {dx}{dy}=\frac {1}{1+y^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
y = \tan x
$$
$$
\frac {dy}{dx} = \sec^2 x = 1+\tan^2 x = 1+y^2
$$
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = 1+y^2
$$
$$
\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{1+y^2}
$$
$$
\frac d{dx} \arctan y = \frac 1 {1+y^2}
$$

Is the reciprocal of $dy/dx$ really $dx/dy$?  It certainly would be if $dy$ and $dx$ were actual numbers.  The fact that these are each others reciprocal's is an instance of the chain rule.

Comment: "The fact that these are each others reciprocal's is an instance of the chain rule." <- Why?

Comment: @Nick : The chain rule can be written as $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dy}{du}\cdot\dfrac{du}{dx}$.  Apply that to the case where $x$ and $y$ are the same variable: $\dfrac{dx}{dx} = \dfrac{dx}{du}\cdot\dfrac{du}{dx}$, and remember that $dx/dx=1$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: So, you're using the fact that $a\cdot b = 1$ implies that $a$ is the multiplicative inverse of $b$ and vice versa. Thanks for this explanation :D

Comment: $\dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ and $\dfrac{\Delta x}{\Delta y}$ _are_ reciprocals (because those are real numbers). (P.S. $\Delta y$ is defined as $y(x+\Delta x)-y(x)$.) Thus, by taking the limit as $\Delta x\to0$, we have that $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ and $\dfrac{dx}{dy}$ are reciprocals.

Comment: @columbus8myhw : That's almost right.  A problem arises when the set of values of $\Delta x$ for which $\Delta y=0$ is not bounded away from $\Delta x=0$.  That gives you zeros in a denominator.  But that problem is surmountable by a bit of additional argument. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.
$$ x=\tan(y)$$
$$dx = \sec^2(y)dy$$

Therefore.

$$\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=\int\frac{\sec^2(y)}{1+\tan^2(y)}dy$$
$$=\int\frac{\sec^2(y)}{\sec^2(y)}dy$$
$$=\int dy$$
$$=y+c$$
$$=\arctan(x)+c$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the formula for geometric series,
$${1\over 1+x^2}=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\cdots+(-x^2)^n+\cdots
$$
Integrating,
$$
\begin{align}
\int 1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\cdots+(-x^2)^n+\cdots dx&=x-{x^3\over3}+{x^5\over5}-{x^7\over7}+\cdots\\
&=\arctan x\\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking,$f^{-1}$ is the inverse of $f(x)$, not $\frac{1}{f(x)}$.

For example, $\tan^{-1}x=\arctan x$, $\sin^{-1}x=\arcsin x$.

Comment: Although both $f^{-1}$ and $\frac 1 f$ are inverses - just different types. One's a function inverse, and ones a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: $\dfrac1{f(x)}$ is indeed the inverse of $f(x)$, if "inverse" means multiplicative inverse.  But this is really about the (compositional) inverse of $f$, not of $f(x)$, but then evaluated at $x$. ${}\qquad{}$